# Meaning of the <*> symbol

Tags: perl, io, perldoc

I've recently been exposed to a bit of Perl code, and some aspects of it are still elusive to me. This is it:

```
@collection = <*>;
```

I understand that the at-symbol defines `collection` as an array. I've also searched around a bit, and landed on perldoc, specifically at the part about [I/O Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators). I found the null filelhandle specifically interesting; code follows.

```
while (<>) {
    ...
}
```

On the same topic I have also noticed that this syntax is also valid:

```
while (<*.c>) {
    ...
}
```

According to perldoc It is actually calling an internal function that invokes `glob` in a manner similar as the following code:

```
open(FOO, "echo *.c | tr -s ' \t\r\f' '\\012\\012\\012\\012'|");
while (<FOO>) {
    ...
}
```

### Question

What does the less-than, asterisk, more-than (**<*>**) symbol mentioned on the first line actually do? Is it a reference to an internally open and referenced glob? Would it be a special case, such as the null filehandle? Or can it be something entirely different, like a legacy implementation?

Comment: it is a  file directive , <*.c> is same as doing 'ls *.c'

Comment: I see - would then <*> be a reference to 'all files'?

Comment: yes , all files and directories and links etc , same as ls *. <> is same as reading from STDIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<>` (the *diamond operator*) is used in two different syntaxes.

`<*.c>`, `<*>` etc. is shorthand for the [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) built-in function. So `<*>` returns a list of all files and directories in the current directory. (Except those beginning with a dot; use `<* .*>` for that).

`<$fh>` is shorthand for calling `readline($fh)`. If no filehandle is specified (`<>`) the magical *ARGV handle is assumed, which is a list of files specified as command line arguments, or standard input if none are provided. As you mention, [the perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators) covers both in detail.

How does Perl distinguish the two? It checks if the thing inside `<>` is either a bare filehandle or a *simple* scalar reference to a filehandle (e.g. `$fh`). Otherwise, it calls `glob()` instead. This even applies to stuff like `<$hash{$key}>` or `<$x >` - it will be interpreted as a call to `glob()`. If you read the perldoc a bit further on, this is explained - and it's recommended that you use `glob()` explicitly if you're putting a variable inside `<>` to avoid these problems.

Comment: Clear and concise answer, and very well documented; accepted.

Comment: BTW since it hasn't been mentioned, when in need to search info over the internet, it is good to know that the `<>` is called *diamond operator*, thus *perl diamond operator* would yield the appropriate results in google search.

Comment: That is a very good point, thanks! I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Learning something new every day. Thanks for the bit, psxls.

Answer (score 1):

It collects all filenames in the current directory and save them to the array collection. Except those beginning with a dot. It's the same as:

```
@collection = glob "*";
```

Comment: I see. Coming from .NET / Java world, I find the amount of ways you can do the same thing in Perl very exquisite. Thanks for the glob sample!